# FETCH : from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: php, javascript, fetch, cors, postman

Tengo este problema, en Postman esta API hecha en php devuelve todos los resultados, cuando lo hago de desde javascript me tira ese error , cuando veo el código de Postman me sugiere esto:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("key", "1234");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "1234");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://serversoftic.dyndns-ip.com:8083/api/pacientes_api", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Cuando lo ejecuto tira el mismo error :"

```
Access to fetch at 'http://serversoftic.dyndns-ip.com:8083/api/pacientes_api' 
from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header 
field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers 
in preflight response.
appGet.js:16 GET http://serversoftic.dyndns-ip.com:8083/api/pacientes_api net::ERR_FAILED
```

Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: te invito a leer la pregunta y las respuestas para comprender un poco mas, debes configurar tu CORS en tu servidor

Comment: y que es lo que tendria que hacer en mi servidor?, ya probe de todo

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); Lo tenia escrito con ' y solo funciono con " ---- increible, gracias!